# Enter jqgrid link in grouping row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

- **429900**
- Contract    Units    Actions
- C1         10        Show
- C2         20        Show
- C3         25        Show
- C4         25        Show
- **80**

I would like to add the Show link to the grouping header row i.e. **429900 - Show** and/or to the grouping footer in Actions Column( next to cell with 80-group total).

Thanks in advance

Comment: using groupText: ['<b>{0} - <a href="/TIPS/Growers/... 1 2011">Show</a>&nbsp;</b>'] creates the **429900 - Show**

Comment: using  { name: 'Actions', sortable: false, formatter: actionFormat, summaryTpl: '<a href="/TIPS/Growers/Inventory/{0}">Show</a>&nbsp;', summaryType: function () { } } sets the show link next to the 80 total but - {0} is undefined. Need to figure the group col val(429900 above).